# Where to put @Grab annotation in Grails Service

Tags: grails, dependencies

I have the following groovy code ,and i excute it on grails console plugin . it works fine .
However, i want to reuse it in grails' service.

```
@Grab( 'net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.18' )

import org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser
def html = '''<p>
             |  I wanted to try to <span id="blk1">match</span> the inner part
             |  of the string<span id="blk2"> between </span> the span tags <span>where</span>
             |</p>'''.stripMargin()

def content = new XmlSlurper( new SAXParser() ).parseText( html )

List<String> spans = content.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'SPAN' && it.@id?.text()?.startsWith( 'blk' ) }*.text()
```

**ATTEMPT1:**

```
    import groovy.grape.Grape;
    @Grab( 'net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.18' )
class MyService {
//..
     
}
```

**ERR :**

```
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message can't create byte arrau at ../../../src/share/instrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 793
```

i tried to put @Grab annotation before method that shall do the code above, i have an error.
i tries to put @Grab before class ,the same result; it's an error also .

Where do i put @Grab annotation .

**ATTEMPT2:**

When i add the dependency above in BuildConfig.groovy ,

```
runtime( 'net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.18')
```

**ERR :**
i get the following error :

```
grails> --stacktrace -Dserver.port=9090 run-app
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Error Error running script --stacktrace -Dserver.port=9090 run-app: org/apache/xerces/dom/DeferredElementNSImpl (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/dom/DeferredElementNSImpl
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.synchronizeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.getDocumentElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:74)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:58)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:30)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
| Error Error running script --stacktrace -Dserver.port=9090 run-app: org/apache/xerces/dom/DeferredElementNSImpl
```

**ATTEMPT3:**
Likewise,adding the dependency in BuildConfig.groovy did not solve the problem.

```
   dependencies {
        //....
       // .......
       compile( 'net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.18'){
            excludes 'xercesImpl'
        }
    }
```

Reference: http://www.grailsforum.co.uk/showthread.php/2143-New-to-grails-problem-with-JAVA-jar-dependencies#post_message_2323

Even i use the solution above, it works only when compiling.

**ATTEMPT4**:
I execute the following command to add the dependency  ; but in vain :

```
grails install-dependency net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.18 --dir=lib
```

**ERR**
And i get , this error message :

```
 Packaging Grails application.....
| Error Error running script  run-app: org/apache/xerces/dom/DeferredElementNSImpl (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practices to Put all libraries either :

1. in `lib` folder then Refersh , or in

   or
2. in `conf/BuildConfig.groovy`

Hiowever , if you want to use Grape , Use the following syntax:

```
import groovy.grape.Grape
Grape.grab(group:'net.sourceforge.nekohtml', module:'nekohtml', version:'1.9.18')
```

or

```
groovy.grape.Grape.initGrape()
@Grab(group='net.sourceforge.nekohtml', module='nekohtml', version='1.9.18')
public class MyService{


}
```